# Edit Aufs Tmpfs partition size

Tags: ram, initramfs, tmpfs

I followed this instruction https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash to create a aufs RAMDISK for my xubuntu. It creates a 512MB Filesystem. SO, HOW CAN I CHANGE THAT SIZE FOR SAVING RAM?